# File Signing using BouncyCastle in a HSM Environement

Tags: java, bouncycastle, private-key, pkcs#11

I have used

```java
public static void signContent(String cfgFilePath , String alias ,String tokenPassword , String inputFile , String outputFile){
            try {
                CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

                Provider pkcs11 = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
                pkcs11 = pkcs11.configure(cfgFilePath);

                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",pkcs11);
                keyStore.load(null, tokenPassword.toCharArray());

                logger.log(Level.INFO,"Keystore size : "+keyStore.size());
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "certificate found for alias given : "+keyStore.getCertificate(alias));
                PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, tokenPassword.toCharArray());

                logger.log(Level.INFO,"pvt key :" + privateKey);
                logger.log(Level.INFO,"pvt key  algorithm: "+privateKey.getAlgorithm());// RSA
                logger.log(Level.INFO,"key format : "+privateKey.getFormat()); // prints null

                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
                List certList = new ArrayList();
                certList.add(cert);

                Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
                generator.addCertificates(certs);

                ContentSigner sha256Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privateKey);

                generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                        new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(sha256Signer, cert));//NO I18N

                byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)); // Reading byte content from the input file

                CMSProcessableByteArray cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content);
                CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(cmsData, true);
                // Get the signed JSON as a byte array
                byte[] signedJson = signedData.getEncoded();

                Files.write(Paths.get(outputFile),signedJson);  // writing the signed content to the output file.
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception Occurred while signing the input file : ## STACKTRACE ##");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

to sign a file for integrity verification.

But im getting error on

```
org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: Supplied key (sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.ems.silentupdate.FileSigningHandler.signContent(FileSigningHandler.java:85)
    at com.ems.silentupdate.FileSigningHandler.main(FileSigningHandler.java:115)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi.engineInitSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1351)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:636)
    ... 3 more
```

Whats the problem.. Im also new to HSM related works, if explaining how does HSM works will be appreciated.
Could anyone explain how to sign a file with private key that is stored in a HSM format.
Im using java 11 to sign , and bouncycastle version - bcpkix-jdk15on.jar , bcprov-jdk15on.jar

Comment: PKCS11 `Key` objects only work with the PKCS11 `Provider` (and you don't put yours in the default list) so for `JcaContentSignerProvider.setProvider` use `pkcs11` NOT `"BC"`

Comment: Yes , i have tried,  but throws NoSuchAlgorithmException on SHA256WITHRSA

Comment: Which algorithms are supported in SunPKCS11 varies -- it depends on what is implemented by the device in use AND also enabled by the config in SunPKCS11. Check your config to make sure this is enabled or not disabled, as applicable. If so and you get NoSuchAlgorithm, your device doesn't support that signature and you can't use it. Some devices have their own configuration or permissions that need to be set up outside of Java, either globally or per key, but you don't say what your device is (and if you do there may or may not be anyone here familiar with it).